# Find_by_sql and calculated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using find my sql, and I want to calculate something in the database and add to my model.

I wil try to simplify the code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :comments_count

end
```

And somewhere else:

```
@users = User.find_by_sql("select * (select count(*) from comments where user_id=u.id) as comments_count from Users u")


@user.map{|u| puts u.comments_count}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got it.
It has nothing to do with attr_accessor. I had to remove it.

```
@users = User.find_by_sql("select * (select count(*) from comments where user_id=u.id) as comments_count from Users u")

@user.map do |u|
  puts u.comments_count if @user.has_attribute?(:comments_count)
end
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the solution in details? How is it different from what is in the Q aside map call? I face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord will, unfortunately, not just match any selected columns to attributes on the model.  However, something like that would probably be fairly easy to put together.  First you'd need to overload `find_by_sql` to something like this -

```
def self.find_by_sql(sql)
    values = connection.select_all(sql)

    objects = []

    values.each do |row|
        objects << self.new(row)
    end

    objects
end
```

Then the initialize function for your model can mass assign the schema-based attributes, and then handle assigning your custom attributes.  Its not as clean or simple a solution as you were probably hoping for, but it should accomplish the task.  And you could probably write the initialize function so that it is fairly generic, in that it can mass assign all the schema-based attributes, and then match leftover keys that were passed in with any attributes that may be present on `self`.

Comment: Are you sure? I have found the following: www.railsrocket.com/find_by_sql and he says that I can do that

Comment: I apologize, I was not aware of this functionality - the version I was using was quite old, so that may have been the problem.  However, if this works as described in that article, what exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is that it doesnt work :)  . I am not sure if attr_accessor is ok? how can I access the attributes?